# Is using a pointer a good way to prefetch data?

Tags: c++, pointers, caching, memory

Recently I've been reading about writing more cache friendly code, and I'm trying to use it in practice I have however stumbled upon something slightly confusing.

From what I understand prefetching data allows the cpu to focus on the job at hand and not get distracted by having to fetch data from various locations in memory. A specific example that I saw in a lecture about data oriented design by Mike Acton even mentioned that storing class members locally is beneficial to performance. (e.g. using int some_count = m_SomeCount in the condition in a for loop instead of using the member m_SomeCount itself as the class member is stored elsewhere in memory than the local variables so it can't be cached properly).

Having that said, see the (trivial) code snippet below:

```
// Fetching the element several times
m_Entities[entity_id].status &= ~Entity::StatusFlags::kActive;
m_Entities[entity_id].components.clear();
m_Entities[entity_id].DoSomething(); 

// Fetching the element once, though now a pointer is used
Entity::Entity* entity = &m_Entities[entity_id];
entity->status &= ~Entity::StatusFlags::kActive;
entity->components.clear();
entity->DoSomething();
```

Using the second method (using a pointer) you'd only have to fetch the element from the vector once, I was wondering if this actually benefits "cache-friendliness" and performance in general as the pointer still needs to be dereferenced every time you want to modify the element.

Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Write clear, understandable, maintainable code first.  Then profile to determine if micro optimizations like this are even needed.

Comment: Generate optimized assembly and look for yourself. Given the example you just posted, unless `m_Entities` is of a type that overloads `operator []`, I sincerely doubt you're getting any benefit whatsoever in optimized code.

Comment: Also in general, compilers are pretty good at the optimization you talk about. And as @NathanOliver said, write good code first, then optimize. In quite a few cases, premature optimization may actually make your code slower, as it may preempt the compiler from making a potentially more optimized code path.

Comment: You are overthinking it. Write clear understandable code. If it doesn't perform as well as you expect then *profile it* - only then try to optimize.  My money is on you not being able to guess up-front what piececes of code are the performance bottleneck. Trying to micro-optimize up-front is just wasting time - trust your optimizer or prove it wrong before sacrificing code clarity.

Comment: I don't know the answer but my gut feeling is if you have to dereference a pointer to find the variable its probably not going to be any more efficient that dereferencing the `this` pointer (which is what accessing members entails.

Comment: This isn't so much about optimizing performance for a specific project as it is about understanding what happens under the hood. I get that you should first make sure your code is actually good before optimizing the details. That doesn't mean I don't want to know how to optimize the details though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd call this 'prefetching' - to me that term refers to much lower-level techniques that will load a cache or pipeline in anticipation that the data will be needed by the CPU soon.

However putting aside that terminology difference, pretty much any compiler today (with optimizations enabled) will fold the expression `m_Entities[entity_id]` into a register to use as a pointer for the subsequent accesses. Unless there's a possibility that `m_Entities` or `entity_id` can be aliased such that they might change in the subsequent uses.

And even if *you* know that no such aliasing can (or should) occur, compilers sometimes don't have enough information to be able to make that guarantee.

Using a local pointer can be a clean way to ensure that the compiler doesn't have to worry about the possibility of aliasing.

It's still an optimization that is unlikely to be measurably helpful in most cases, though I've certainly come across code where it also has the benefit of making the code more readable. I think it would be hard to argue that it makes the code less readable, and the compiler is free to optimize out storing the pointer anywhere if it doesn't need to.  I'm not sure if it should ever be turned into a pessimization (anit-optimization).

The only real downsides I can see are:

- someone might argue that it's unnecessary or less readable
- if the code *depends* on aliasing (or a non-aliased side-effect that changes the indexing expression), then the behavior becomes different and you have introduced a bug.

Comment: Thank you!! Yeah sorry, I'm pretty new to the whole concept of cache optimization. So now I wonder, would having `entity_id` be a const int parameter be a sufficient hint for the compiler that `m_Entities[entity_id]` shouldn't be aliased?

Comment: If `entity_id` is an `int` argument to the function (it doesn't even need to be `const`) then it can't be aliased unless the address to it has been provided to some other function.